# How to echo a value in a mysql table PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM playerCount WHERE `count` >= 0") or die(mysql_error());
```

How can I get the value of count in the table playerCount, I don't think I'm doing this right.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? From what it looks, you have a `count` field in your `playerCount` table?

Comment: `SELECT \`count\` FROM playerCount WHERE \`count\` >= 0`?

Comment: Yes, I have a field count in playerCount table, am I doing this right?$result = mysql_query("SELECT `count` FROM playerCount") or die(mysql_error());
echo $result;

Comment: @Sean, +1, didn't realize that the OP could have wanted the value of count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing the query, you have to fetch the results, and then you can echo the value -

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `count` FROM playerCount") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
      echo $row['count'];
}
```

just be aware that the `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. You will want to use `mysqli` or `PDO` to write new code. see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: @Sean +1 again for pointing the link.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the total number of records where `count` column's value is greater than or equal to `0`, your query should be (notice the use of `count()` function):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(1) as totalPayerCount FROM playerCount WHERE `count` >= 0") or die(mysql_error());
```

Edit: (After OP posted the image of table definition)

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `count` FROM playerCount WHERE `count` >= 0") or die(mysql_error());

$resultSet = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if (!empty($resultSet)) {
   echo $resultSet['count'];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I just put the >= 0 because I didn't know what else to put. I just want the value of count.

Comment: I'm using : $result = mysql_query("SELECT count(1) FROM playerCount WHERE count >= 0") or die(mysql_error());
echo $result;

Comment: @user2608564, you should make your question clearer in that case, not just put "whatever".  So what should we base the count on?  Show us your table definition and please make your question clearer.

Comment: http://puu.sh/3JleB.png it's just a value in playerCount table, I'm just trying to get and echo that value